# Rename pandas column of type datetime pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i have dataframe like this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data={'2021-11-21':['10','20'],'2021-11-14':['39','21']})

df
2021-11-21    2021-11-14
10            39
20            21
```

i want rename columns like this:

```
curr_week_2021-11-21    prev_week_2021-11-14
10                      39
20                      21
```

i tried this:

```
df_cols=df.columns.to_list()
df=df.rename(columns={'2021-11-21':'curr_week_'+df_cols[0],'2021-11-14':'prev_week_'+df_cols[1]})
```

but it did not work.

Comment: works for me. Are you certain that your column names are string? Also, `df.columns = ['curr_week_', 'prev_week_'] + df.columns` would work as well.

Comment: i have an error: `TypeError: Cannot broadcast np.ndarray with operand of type <class 'list'>`

Comment: You must use an older version of numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `rename` create a dict mapping:

```
df = df.rename(columns={c: f"{p}_{str(c)}"
                  for c, p in zip(df.columns, ['curr_week', 'prev_week'])})
print(df)

# Output:
  curr_week_2021-11-21 prev_week_2021-11-14
0                   10                   39
1                   20                   21
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it programmatically with an arbitrary list of prefixes would be to use `map`/`zip`/`join`:

```
prefixes = ['curr_week', 'prev_week']
df.columns = map('_'.join, zip(prefixes, df.columns))
```

output:

```
  curr_week_2021-11-21 prev_week_2021-11-14
0                   10                   39
1                   20                   21
```

Comment: `TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, datetime.date found`  . i am getting this error.

Comment: I see, you don't have strings. Can you try `df.columns = map('_'.join, zip(prefixes, map(str, df.columns)))`